# Assign csv files to a collection of dictionaries (list) with file name as the keys and file content as the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

i have a problem with the iteration process in python, I've tried and search the solutions, but i think this more complex than my capability (fyi, I've been writing code for 1 month).

The case:
Let say i have 3 csv files (the actual is 350 files), they are file_1.csv, file_2.csv, file_3.csv. I've done the iteration process/algorithm to create all of the filenames in into single list.

each csv contains single column with so many rows.
i.e.

```
#actual cvs much more like this:
# for file_1.csv:
value_1
value_2
value_3
```

Below is not the actual csv content (i mean i  have converted them into array/series)

file_1.csv --> [['value_1'],['value_2'],['value_3']]
file_2.csv --> [['value_4'],['value_5']]
file_3.csv --> [['value_6']]

```
#first step was done, storing csv files name to a list, so it can be read and use in csv function.

filename = ['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv', 'file_3.csv']
```

I want the result as a list:

```
#assigning a empty list
result = []
```

Desired result

```
print (result)

out:
[{'keys': 'file_1', 'values': 'value_1, value_2, value_3'},
{'keys': 'file_2', 'values': 'value_4, value_5'}
{'keys': 'file_3', 'values': 'value_6'}]
```

See above that the result's keys are no more containing ('.csv') at the end of file name, they are all replaced. And note that csv values (previously as a list of list or series) become one single string - separated with comma.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you very much

Comment: To join a list of values into the string you want, use `join()`: , like this: `", ".join(list_of_values)`. You need a few more tools, so work on the problem step by step.

Comment: @alexis thanks for your comment. yes, i've used that. But the problem is much more like assigning those values into partitioned dictionary for each file.

Comment: Then please edit your question and narrow down your problem. A question should be about one specific problem, not one complete program. If you had been more specific I would not have answered a part you don't need.

Comment: Is `[['value_1'],['value_2'],['value_3']]` the _actual_ content of the files (do the files actually contain square brackets) or is that just part of your explanation? Perhaps you could post a few lines of one of the files as an example?

Comment: @WillKeeling sorry for the wrong explanation.. no, they are not actual values in csv rather ive converted them into array/series form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that the contents of the files is already pretty much in the format you need them (bar the line endings) and you have the names of the 350 files in a list, there isn't a huge amount of processing you need to do. It's mainly a question of reading the contents of each file, and stripping the newline characters.

For example:

```
import os

result = []

filenames = ['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv', 'file_3.csv']

for name in filenames:
    # Set the filename minus extension as 'keys'
    file_data = {'keys': os.path.basename(name).split('.')[0]}
    with open(name) as f:
        # Read the entire file
        contents = f.read()
        # Strip the line endings (and trailing comma), and set as 'values'
        file_data['values'] = contents.replace(os.linesep, ' ').rstrip(',')
    result.append(file_data)

print(result)
```

Comment: Hi.. your code works, but I met unexpected result that my values contain back slashing `(\)` and cannot be split.

here's the part i tuned, credit to parvbanks:
    `line [10]
     with open (name, 'r') as infile: #with open(name) as f:
        # Read the entire file
        tempvalue = []
        for line in infile.readlines():
            tempvalue.append(line.strip())
        contents = " ".join(tempvalue)
        # Strip the line endings (and trailing comma), and set as 'values'
        file_data['values'] = contents
    result.append(file_data)` Again thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to answer this to the best of my capacity (I'm a newbie too).

## Step1: Reading those 350 filenames

(if you've not figured out already, you could use glob module for this step)

Define the directory where the files are placed, let's say 'C:\Test'

```
directory = "C:/Test"
import glob
filename = sorted (glob.glob(directory, + "/*.csv"))
```

This will read all the 'CSV' files in the directory.

## Step2: Reading CSV files and mapping them to dictionaries

```
result = []
import os
for file in files:
    filename = str (os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]) # removes the CSV extension from the filename
    with open (file, 'r') as infile:
        tempvalue = []
        tempdict = {}
        print (filename)
        for line in infile.readlines():
            tempvalue.append(line.strip()) # strips the lines and adds them to a list of temporary values
        value = ",".join(tempvalue)        # converts the temp list to a string
        tempdict[filename] = value         # Assigns the filename as key and the contents as value to a temporary dictionary
        result.append(tempdict)            # Adds the new temp dictionary for each file to the result list
print (result)
```

This piece of code should work (though there might be a smaller and more pythonic code someone else might share).

Comment: Hi.. thank you for your answer. Very helpful, but i met some error, specially at the step 1.

`bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`

but, with your code I can find tuning next answer by will keeling to the code i was searching for. Again, thanks.